# bioconda: No such file or directory mulled-build

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

I'm trying to build a new package (`verifybamid`) for bioconda. I'm running this on a minimal Linux VM with docker, conda, bioconda-utils etc. set up. `conda build verifybamid` works. When I try `./simulate-travis.py --packages verifybamid --loglevel=debug` things work fine at first, but eventually I get a `No such file or directory: mulled-build` invoked by test_package(). According to the [bioconda-utils](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-utils):

> each built package can now be tested in an isolated busybox container
>   thanks to mulled-build and involucro. This will catch issues where a
>   recipe fails to specify libs (e.g., libgcc) in the run dependencies.

but which package is it that I have to install for this to work?

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install galaxy-lib. Actually, it should come with your requiremets.txt file as dependency of bioconda-utils. If not please do a `conda install galaxy-lib` and you will get mulled-build to create very efficient Docker containers out of Conda packages.

Cheers,
Bjoern

Comment: That worked! Cool! Thanks! BTW: galaxy-lib is not mentioned in any of the requirements.txt file of the current bioconda commit